# How to extend an existing control with UI

Tags: wpf

Let's say I'd like to extend the default WPF `Window` class to always contain a tool bar (docked to the top border), where the item source is bound to a dependency property which can be set from outside my class. And my default WPF `Window` class should always contain a panel (docked to the bottom border) with a close button which is already wired up to call the `Close` function of the original `Window class`.

I could create a custom class inheriting from `Window` and create all the necessary controls and bindings in code, but is there a way to extend an existing class using XAML? At least for the UI part of the extension?

Comment: You would create a default ControlTemplate for your Window, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32441842/1136211

Comment: Instead of extending a window, i would consider creating a usercontrol from the toolbar. But I rarely see the need for multiple windows.

Comment: Andy: How would a "usercontrol from the toolbar" add the close button to my window?

Comment: Clemens: Thank you, I'll try my luck with a `ContolTemplate`.

Comment: You can put content inside a usercontrol, if you build your usercontrol right. Templates can't have code without adding code behind to a resource dictionary. My preference is to put extra logic in a usercontrol, where you would reasonably expect extra logic to be. The usercontrol can find it's parent window if you want a close button in it.